# VHDL - Dynamic std_logic_vector size

Tags: dynamic, vector, logic, std, vhdl

Is there a way in VHDL whereby I can declare a `std_logic_vector` such that the size of it keeps changing depending on the size of the input?

What I would like to do is, input a `std_logic_vector` of 8 bits and then have a dynamic `std_logic_vector` signal that stores the input value. Then, the next time the input value is received again, I concatenate the value to the end of the dynamic signal and so on.

Comment: VHDL is a hardware description language. implementing a std_logic_vector is like installing a bunch of wires. the amount of wires can not be changed dynamically!

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you are trying to achieve a std_logic_vector that changes dynamically after compiling and elaboration, you cannot do it. If you are looking for it to be dynamic once, at elaboration, then that is possible (by not specifying a range).  Typically if you need a truely "dynamic width" you need to specify the width as wide as your widest possible input, and then pad the other input (typically with 0s).

Comment: Thank you Josh, I'm going to use your suggestion of padding the useless bits with 0s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you're looking for is not possible. The size of the `std_logic_vector` must be known at compile time. Because VHDL is used to describe hardware, a `std_logic_vector` with a dynamic size would correspond to dynamic hardware (e.g. more registers being instantiated during run-time). This is not possible.

What you're describing sounds like a shift-register. You could define a `std_logic_vector(MAX_LEN-1 downto 0)` and then shift each byte to a higher order byte position when you receive a new value.